# How to verify weather the logged in user is a member of google group to which I am an admin

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-groups

I have a scenario in my web application where I want to verify the logged in user is a member of the specific google groups. If he is a member of the group I can give some access permissions. How to verify this programatically. I am using google authentication to login to my application and I have a google group with a list of members.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail your question and what do you want to achieve ? What services are you using - the more details the better.

Comment: I have given storage viewer access to a google-groups mail(example@googlegroups.com) on my gcp storage bucket. In my web application when a user login with gmail address, I am getting the IAM permissions of a bucket using a service account which returns a google group name. Now I want to check weather the logged in user belongs to this group or not .

Comment: By "google group" you mean [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/) ?

Comment: yes Google groups

Answer (score 0):

There is a [method from the members API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#get_all_members) which retrieves the members of a specific group, you can use that method to obtain the members of the group and look if the logged user matches any of those members.

I hope you find this useful!